# How do I set the animation color of a LinearProgressIndicator?

Tags: flutter

The [LinearProgressIndicator documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html) helpfully displays the existence of a valueColor property and even mentions "To specify a constant color use: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(color).", but if I try to set the color I get an error that LinearProgressIndicator has no instance setter for valueColor and the constructor for the class only accepts a key and a numerical value for the progress amount.

If I want a LinearProgressIndicator with a custom color do I need to create my own class? Is there really no way to specify this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like it's controlled from the Theme's accent color:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b670ce4bcc49bbab745221eae24fcebcbc9dba7c/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/progress_indicator.dart#L61

Wrap the relevant subtree in a modified Theme setting the accentColor to whatever you might like.

Answer (score 98):

If you want to set a constant color you can use :

```dart
CircularProgressIndicator(
  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
)
```

Answer (score 10):

```dart
LinearProgressIndicator(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFFB4B4B4),
    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can provide in the below way,

```
LinearProgressIndicator( valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color> (Color(0xFFA86E52)),),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearProgressIndicator(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.yellow)  ,
      color: Colors.red,
      minHeight: 10,
),
```